# JSON get data with different names

Tags: php, json, loops, object

I'm having trouble traversing this JSON bacause it had different names. How can I loop and get the data inside "general_release" or "special_immigrant_juvenile_fundings" ? I'm pretty new in json and I think this kind of thing is quite high for me to handle.

This is the json, please ignore the null values :

```
{
"referral": {
    "PD_Subject": "Urgent Please Respond",
    "PD_Location": "1",
    "referral_start_date": "10/19/2016 9:12 AM",
    "referral_end_date": "10/31/2016 9:12 AM",
    "publicdefender": "Rommel",
    "email_pd": "Rommel@yahoo.com",
    "number_pd": "123456",
    "socialworker": "Rommel",
    "email_sw": "rommel@yahoo.com",
    "number_sw": "12345567",
    "PB_firstname": "Rommel",
    "PB_lastname": "Semira",
    "PB_mobile": "12345678",
    "alternate_mobile": "1234578",
    "other_names": "Rommel",
    "PB_email_address": "staypot@rocketmail.com",
    "PB_address": "123213123",
    "PB_birthdate": "10/05/2016 9:12 AM",
    "PB_gender": "Male",
    "PB_birthplace": "Australia\r\n",
    "language": "English",
    "other_language": "Spanish",
    "guardian_fullname": "Rommel",
    "PB_relationshipToClient": "1234568",
    "guardian_address": "qwertyu",
    "guardian_number": "123123123",
    "guardian_alternatenumber": "123123123",
    "juvenile_dateOfArrest": "10/27/2016",
    "juvenile_charge": "123123123",
    "juvenile_disposition": "qweqweqwe",
    "PB_juvenile_courtDate": "10/22/2016",
    "court_date_location": "qweqweq",
    "PB_history_dateOfArrest": "10/29/2016",
    "history_charge": "qweqwe",
    "history_county": "Alpine",
    "registed_sss": "1",
    "history_outcome": "qweqweqwe",
    "referral_notes": "qweqweqwe"
},
"general_release": {
    "sijs_firm_name": "",
    "sijs_street_address": "",
    "sijs_city": "",
    "sijs_state": "",
    "sijs_zipcode": "",
    "sijs_telephone_number": "",
    "sijs_fax": "",
    "sijs_email_address": "",
    "sijs_attorney": "",
    "sijs_county": "",
    "sijs_mailing_address": "",
    "sijs_branch_name": "",
    "sijs_case_name": "",
    "sijs_case_number": "",
    "sijs_child_name": "",
    "sijs_date_of_birth": "",
    "sijs1_datetime_hearing": "",
    "sijs_department": "",
    "sijs_room": "",
    "sijs_judicial_officer": "",
    "sijs_attorney_presents": "",
    "sijs_child_country": "",
    "sijs_child_juvenile_court": "",
    "sijs_placed_under_custody_name": "",
    "sijs_custody_entity_name": "",
    "sijs_state_of_agency_location": "",
    "sijs_california_court_date": "",
    "general_appointment_id": "276",
    "type_of_form": "general_release"
},
"special_immigrant_juvenile_fundings": {
    "_token": " ti9qqsqzOMRzEo4PZd1I2wwWFSdyIM3jrXJTAenK",
    "sijs_firm_name": "",
    "sijs_street_address": "",
    "sijs_city": "",
    "sijs_state": "",
    "sijs_zipcode": "",
    "sijs_telephone_number": "",
    "sijs_fax": "",
    "sijs_email_address": "",
    "sijs_attorney": "",
    "sijs_county": "",
    "sijs_mailing_address": "",
    "sijs_branch_name": "",
    "sijs_case_name": "",
    "sijs_case_number": "",
    "sijs_child_name": "",
    "sijs_date_of_birth": "",
    "sijs1_datetime_hearing": "",
    "sijs_department": "",
    "sijs_room": "",
    "sijs_judicial_officer": "",
    "sijs_attorney_presents": "",
    "sijs_child_country": "",
    "sijs_child_juvenile_court": "",
    "sijs_placed_under_custody_name": "",
    "sijs_custody_entity_name": "",
    "sijs_state_of_agency_location": "",
    "sijs_california_court_date": "",
    "general_appointment_id": "276",
    "type_of_form": "special_immigrant_juvenile_fundings"
}
```

}

Comment: json_decode() than loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) here for getting values from json string as:

```
<?php
$json = '{
"referral": {
    "PD_Subject": "Urgent Please Respond",
    "PD_Location": "1",
    "referral_start_date": "10/19/2016 9:12 AM",
    "referral_end_date": "10/31/2016 9:12 AM",
    "publicdefender": "Rommel",
    "email_pd": "Rommel@yahoo.com",
    "number_pd": "123456",
    "socialworker": "Rommel",
    "email_sw": "rommel@yahoo.com",
    "number_sw": "12345567",
    "PB_firstname": "Rommel",
    "PB_lastname": "Semira",
    "PB_mobile": "12345678",
    "alternate_mobile": "1234578",
    "other_names": "Rommel",
    "PB_email_address": "staypot@rocketmail.com",
    "PB_address": "123213123",
    "PB_birthdate": "10/05/2016 9:12 AM",
    "PB_gender": "Male",
    "PB_birthplace": "Australia\r\n",
    "language": "English",
    "other_language": "Spanish",
    "guardian_fullname": "Rommel",
    "PB_relationshipToClient": "1234568",
    "guardian_address": "qwertyu",
    "guardian_number": "123123123",
    "guardian_alternatenumber": "123123123",
    "juvenile_dateOfArrest": "10/27/2016",
    "juvenile_charge": "123123123",
    "juvenile_disposition": "qweqweqwe",
    "PB_juvenile_courtDate": "10/22/2016",
    "court_date_location": "qweqweq",
    "PB_history_dateOfArrest": "10/29/2016",
    "history_charge": "qweqwe",
    "history_county": "Alpine",
    "registed_sss": "1",
    "history_outcome": "qweqweqwe",
    "referral_notes": "qweqweqwe"
},
"general_release": {
    "sijs_firm_name": "",
    "sijs_street_address": "",
    "sijs_city": "",
    "sijs_state": "",
    "sijs_zipcode": "",
    "sijs_telephone_number": "",
    "sijs_fax": "",
    "sijs_email_address": "",
    "sijs_attorney": "",
    "sijs_county": "",
    "sijs_mailing_address": "",
    "sijs_branch_name": "",
    "sijs_case_name": "",
    "sijs_case_number": "",
    "sijs_child_name": "",
    "sijs_date_of_birth": "",
    "sijs1_datetime_hearing": "",
    "sijs_department": "",
    "sijs_room": "",
    "sijs_judicial_officer": "",
    "sijs_attorney_presents": "",
    "sijs_child_country": "",
    "sijs_child_juvenile_court": "",
    "sijs_placed_under_custody_name": "",
    "sijs_custody_entity_name": "",
    "sijs_state_of_agency_location": "",
    "sijs_california_court_date": "",
    "general_appointment_id": "276",
    "type_of_form": "general_release"
},
"special_immigrant_juvenile_fundings": {
    "_token": " ti9qqsqzOMRzEo4PZd1I2wwWFSdyIM3jrXJTAenK",
    "sijs_firm_name": "",
    "sijs_street_address": "",
    "sijs_city": "",
    "sijs_state": "",
    "sijs_zipcode": "",
    "sijs_telephone_number": "",
    "sijs_fax": "",
    "sijs_email_address": "",
    "sijs_attorney": "",
    "sijs_county": "",
    "sijs_mailing_address": "",
    "sijs_branch_name": "",
    "sijs_case_name": "",
    "sijs_case_number": "",
    "sijs_child_name": "",
    "sijs_date_of_birth": "",
    "sijs1_datetime_hearing": "",
    "sijs_department": "",
    "sijs_room": "",
    "sijs_judicial_officer": "",
    "sijs_attorney_presents": "",
    "sijs_child_country": "",
    "sijs_child_juvenile_court": "",
    "sijs_placed_under_custody_name": "",
    "sijs_custody_entity_name": "",
    "sijs_state_of_agency_location": "",
    "sijs_california_court_date": "",
    "general_appointment_id": "276",
    "type_of_form": "special_immigrant_juvenile_fundings"
}
}';

$decode = json_decode($json,true); // use second param as true will return the result in array.
foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
   echo $key."<br/>"; // this will print the heading key
   echo "Values:<br/>";
   foreach ($value as $finalValue) {
      echo $finalValue."<br/>"; // this will print the all values inside the sub array
   }
}
?>
```

*Note that, when you use second param as TRUE this will return the result in array format, if you want to get result in object format than you can ignore the second param, read the manual: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)*

If you just want to get `general_release` data than you can use like that:

```
foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
  if($key == 'general_release'){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already used this code in printing all of the data. But my problem now is how can I get for example "general_release" only?

Comment: @Kiko: answer udpated plz chk

Comment: @Kiko: did u checked?

Comment: Yup.  Thank you for the time.

Comment: Copy. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$temp = $data->general_release;
var_dump($temp->type_of_form);
```

This code works too if I want to store it in a variable.